# Removing duplicate dictionaries in list of dicts based on value uniqueness for a given key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
dicts = [
{'id': 'item1', 'type': 'foo', 'metaId': 'metaId1'},
{'id': 'item2', 'type': 'foo', 'metaId': 'metaId2'},
{'id': 'item3', 'type': 'foo3', 'metaId': 'metaId3'},
{'id': 'item4', 'type': 'foo2', 'metaId': 'metaId2'},
{'id': 'item5', 'type': 'foo3', 'metaId': 'metaId3'},
{'id': 'item6', 'type': 'foo2', 'metaId': 'metaId2'},
{'id': 'item7', 'type': 'foo3', 'metaId': 'metaId3'},
{'id': 'item8', 'type': 'foo2', 'metaId': 'metaId2'},
{'id': 'item9', 'type': 'foo3', 'metaId': 'metaId3'}]
```

I want to loop through the list and create a new list, that contains dictionaries with unique values for key 'type'. I don't care which dictionaries stay, first instance with that key: value  stays, the rest is omitted. So in the end I'd like to see:

```
expected = [
{'id': 'item1', 'type': 'foo', 'metaId': 'metaId1'},
{'id': 'item3', 'type': 'foo3', 'metaId': 'metaId3'},
{'id': 'item4', 'type': 'foo2', 'metaId': 'metaId2'}
]
```

Here is what I tried, definitely not what I need as it returns an empty list. I think I struggle with checking for a value in new sublist of dictionaries to make it excluded

```
keys_to_keep = set()
expected = []
for d in dicts:
    for key, value in d.items():
        if value not in expected:
            keys_to_keep.add(key)
remove_keys = set(d) - keys_to_keep

for d in dicts:
    for k in remove_keys:
        del d[k]
dicts = expected
print(dicts)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unique list of dicts based on keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370660/unique-list-of-dicts-based-on-keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you always get an empty list is because you simply do:

```
dicts = expected
```

And `expected` is simply an empty list, which you never did anything to... not sure why you would think `expected` would ever change.

But you are overcomplicating things. Just keep a set of the unique values, and create a new list of dicts.

```
seen = set()
result = []
for d in dicts:
    if d['type'] not in seen:
        result.append(d)
        seen.add(d['type'])
```

This approach keeps the *first* dictionary encountered with that unique `'type'`.

If, for example, you want the *last* encountered, you could do something like iterate over `dicts` in revere order, so

```
for d in reversed(dicts):
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I definitely overcomplicated it :( I really appreciate this simple solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a temporary dictionary to hold the first dictionary when a particular type is first encountered, and then use the values that end up in it to create the an updated list with one additional line of code.

```
dicts = [{'id': 'item1', 'type': 'foo', 'metaId': 'metaId1'},
         {'id': 'item2', 'type': 'foo', 'metaId': 'metaId2'},
         {'id': 'item3', 'type': 'foo3', 'metaId': 'metaId3'},
         {'id': 'item4', 'type': 'foo2', 'metaId': 'metaId2'},
         {'id': 'item5', 'type': 'foo3', 'metaId': 'metaId3'},
         {'id': 'item6', 'type': 'foo2', 'metaId': 'metaId2'},
         {'id': 'item7', 'type': 'foo3', 'metaId': 'metaId3'},
         {'id': 'item8', 'type': 'foo2', 'metaId': 'metaId2'},
         {'id': 'item9', 'type': 'foo3', 'metaId': 'metaId3'}]

temp = {}
for d in dicts:
    if d['type'] not in temp:
        temp[d['type']] = d

dicts = list(temp.values())  # Update list.

for d in dicts:
    print(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep seen types and add missing to a result slice and also mark it as seen. A function that does this:

```
def transform(dicts):
  seen, result = set(), []
  for d in dicts:
    my_key = d['type']
    if my_key not in seen:
      result.append(d)
      seen.add(my_key)
  return result
```